# Hybris cronjob logging

Tags: java, slf4j, sap-commerce-cloud

I have Job with logger `(Slf4j)` :

**Job Class :**

```
public class MyJob extends AbstractJobPerformable<CronJobModel>
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName());

    @Override
    public PerformResult perform(CronJobModel cronJobModel)
    {
         LOG.info("Test log);
    }
}
```

I want this log to appear in the job log(in hmc). But it doesn't exist there. But logger logs all stuff to console.
Please see below my job Configuration

**Job Configuration:**

[image: Job Configuration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your case is the type of logger which you use `Logger(slf4j)`. 
So to get logs entries you need to use `org.apache.log4j.Logger` as your main `Logger`.
Hybris recommaned `org.apache.log4j.Logger` as Log4j framework to use.
So  add this lines to your class :

- import the package :

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Comment: Yes, it was the case. Thank you. Is it possible to setup hybris to log cronjob with slf4j? In hybris wiki, they say that it's recommended to use slf4j, but also they say that it's not supporting cronjob logs. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, using `slf4j` is recommanded in your developpements, but in CronJob we need to use apache Log4j framework as a native Hybris part, to use slf4j in Jobs, you will need a specific developpement.

Comment: Also, it's an issue for versions 5.x, probably in 6.0+ this is fixed.